# How to add inline image in html email with Micronaut

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, micronaut

I am using Micronaut for web application and I need to send emails. We use velocity template for the email body and we need to include an image in the text. I found out there are 3 ways:

1. Base64 encoded image
2. Content Id attachments
3. Global url link

Since Base64 encoded images in html are not supported by most of the mail clients and since the provided image is not publicly available, I tried the content id attachment. But I couldn't make it work with Micronaut.

Here is a simplified code snippet I have:

```java
Map<String, String> modelMap = new HashMap<>();
modelMap.put("xyz", "aaaaaaa");
TemplateBody<Map<String, String>> body =
    new TemplateBody<>("mail/mail-body.vm", modelMap);

byte[] image = IOUtils.resourceToByteArray("logo.png", getClass().getClassLoader());
Attachment logoAttachment = Attachment.builder()
    .id("logo")
    .filename("something.png")
    .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG)
    .content(image)
    .build();

Email.Builder emailBuilder = Email.builder()
    .from(sender)
    .to(recipient)
    .subject("some-subject")
    .body(body)
    .attachment(createLogoAttachment());

emailSender.send(emailBuilder);
```

The velocity html template looks like this:

```html
<div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed 
    </p>
    <p>
         do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
    </p>
    <p>
        minim veniam
    </p>
    <p>
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut - ${xyz}
    </p>
    <img src="cid:logo" alt="this is logo image"/>
</div>
```

But this way, the image is only a regular attachment, not embedded in html content. The alternative text is shown instead. How can I tell Micronaut that this attachment should be inline? It seems that the **id** attribute I provided is not used at all and the html body does not see the attachment.

The raw mail looks like this:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0

------=_Part_0_2107679308.1690376383642
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_1_706751112.1690376383646"

------=_Part_1_706751112.1690376383646
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
    </p>
    <p>
        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
    </p>
    <p>
        minim veniam
    </p>
    <p>
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut - aaaaaaa
    </p>
    <img src="cid:logo" alt="this is logo image">
</div>

------=_Part_1_706751112.1690376383646--

------=_Part_0_2107679308.1690376383642
Content-Type: image/png; name=something.png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=something.png

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABCkAAAFkCAYAAAANCGFyAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACx ... 

------=_Part_0_2107679308.1690376383642--
```

I didn`t paste the whole base64 image

Comment: how does the raw email looks like, that your sending to the SMTP?

Comment: I pasted it to the question. It is downloaded from Outlook after receiving it.